# CSS multi level menu with nested list

Tags: html, css

[image: css menu illustration]
<sub>(source: [torrent-invites.com](https://image.torrent-invites.com/images/2014/05/18/Untitled-147BEJ.png))</sub>

I want to make pure CSS multi level menu like the picture above. I have tried some tutorial but its not working for me. Menu "xxxxx" and "yyyyy" appear below menu "bbbbb" for my CSS code below.

What I want to make is 3 level menu like the picture above.

This is my HTML for the menu:

```
<span id="nav">
   <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ssss</a>
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">aaaaa</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">bbbbb</a>
                       <ul>
                           <li>xxxxx</li>
                           <li>yyyyy</li>
                       </ul>
                  </li>
             </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">ttttt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">uuuuu</a></li>           
     </ul>                                                           
</span>
```

And this is my minimized CSS code:

```
li {
        list-style:none !important;
}

#nav, #nav ul {
        list-style: none; 
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
}

#nav li {
        line-height:20px;
        float:left;
}

#nav li ul{ 
        display:none; 
}

#nav ul li ul {
    margin-top:-3em;
    margin-left:7em;
}   

#nav ul li:hover ul {
        z-index:99999;
        display:list-item !important;
        position:absolute;
        margin-top:2px;
        margin-left:0px;
        padding: 5px 15px;
        background: #8ac312;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul li {
        float:none;
        padding: 2px 0px;
}


#nav ul li:hover ul li > a:before { 
        content: '» '; 
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated to make my CSS code working like the illustration picture above. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is position relative and absolute. I remove your style and do on my own (simpler, uglier). Code is here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pf7LT/)

And the code is:

CSS:

```
ul { padding:0; margin:0;  }
li { list-style:none; }
li > ul { display: none; }
li:hover > ul { display: block; }
.lvl1 li { margin-right: 10px; display: inline; position:relative; }
.lvl2 { position: absolute; }
.lvl2 li { position: relative; }
.lvl3 { position: absolute; top:0px; left: 50px; }
```

HTML:

```
<span id="nav">
   <ul class='lvl1'>
        <li><a href="#">ssss</a>
              <ul class='lvl2'>
                  <li><a href="#">aaaaa</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">bbbbb</a>
                       <ul class='lvl3'>
                           <li>xxxxx</li>
                           <li>yyyyy</li>
                       </ul>
                  </li>
             </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">ttttt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">uuuuu</a></li>           
     </ul>                                                           
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've edited your code a bit ... check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kau5h/

```
li {
        list-style:none !important;
    position:relative;
}

#nav, #nav ul {
        list-style: none; 
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
}

#nav li {
        line-height:20px;
        float:left;
}
#nav li a {display:block;}
#nav li ul{ 
        display:none; 
    z-index:99999;
        /*display:list-item !important;*/
        position:absolute;
        /*margin-top:2px;*/
        margin-left:0px;

        background: #8ac312;
}
#nav li ul ul {left: 100%; top:0;}
#nav ul li ul {
    /*margin-top:-3em;
    margin-left:7em;*/
}   

#nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul li {
        float:none;
        /*padding: 2px 0px;*/
}
#nav ul ul li {
padding: 5px 15px;
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul li > a:before { 
        /*content: '» '; */
}
```