# List hover not activating

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a menu to appear when hovering over the image, but for some reason it's not appearing. (I'm making it mobile adaptive so the navigation links appear in a hover menu when the browser window is smaller)

Can someone help me figure out why the css rule 'ul.nav-menu:hover' hover isn't working?

```css
#header-nav-menu{
 display:hidden;
 width:44px;
 height:31px;
 background:url(https://animalcorner.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/elephant-1-720x422.jpg) no-repeat;
 margin-left:50px;
}
#header-nav-menu a:hover{
 border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;
}

ul.nav-menu{
 list-style-type:none;
 margin-left: 50px;
 font-size:20px;
 font-family: Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight:100;
 color:#373436;
 padding:0;
 margin:0 0 0 0;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.nav-menu li{
 display:inline-block;
 margin-left:50px;
}
ul.nav-menu a:link{
 color:#373436;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.nav-menu a:visited{
 color:#373436;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.nav-menu a:hover{
 color:#2778BA;
}


/* BELOW ADAPTS WITH SMALLER BROWSER WINDOW */
@media (max-width: 960px) {
ul.nav-menu, ul.nav-menu:active{
 display:none;
 z-index:999999999999999999999999999999999999;
 position:absolute;
 border:1px solid #f0f;
 border-radius: 2px 0 2px 2px;
}
#header-nav-menu{
 display:inline-block;
}

/* BELOW NOT WORKING */
ul.nav-menu:hover{
 display:block;
}
}
```

```html
<nav>
   <a href="#" id="header-nav-menu"></a>
    <ul class="nav-menu">
    <li><a href="../services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="../about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="../contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hover `#header-nav-menu`, you want the `.nav-menu` that comes after it to display. This will do it.

```css
#header-nav-menu{
 display:hidden;
 width:44px;
 height:31px;
 background:url(https://animalcorner.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/elephant-1-720x422.jpg) no-repeat;
 margin-left:50px;
}
#header-nav-menu a:hover{
 border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;
}

ul.nav-menu{
 list-style-type:none;
 margin-left: 50px;
 font-size:20px;
 font-family: Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight:100;
 color:#373436;
 padding:0;
 margin:0 0 0 0;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.nav-menu li{
 display:inline-block;
 margin-left:50px;
}
ul.nav-menu a:link{
 color:#373436;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.nav-menu a:visited{
 color:#373436;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.nav-menu a:hover{
 color:#2778BA;
}
/* BELOW ADAPTS WITH SMALLER BROWSER WINDOW */
@media (max-width: 960px) {
ul.nav-menu, ul.nav-menu:active{
 display:none;
 z-index:999999999999999999999999999999999999;
 position:absolute;
 border:1px solid #f0f;
 border-radius: 2px 0 2px 2px;
}
#header-nav-menu{
 display:inline-block;
}

/* BELOW NOT WORKING */
ul.nav-menu:hover{
 display:block;
}
}

.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrap:hover .nav-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="wrap">
    <a href="#" id="header-nav-menu"></a>
    <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li><a href="../services.html">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="../about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="../contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: @user3760941 np, though that probably won't keep the menu open since when you go to hover over the menu, you're no longer hovering the image, so the menu doesn't show. Do you need help with that, too?

Comment: oh yeah didn't think about that. Yes please!

Comment: I thought 'ul.nav-menu li a:hover{display:block;}' or 'ul.nav-menu a:hover{display:block;}' would work but not sure why it doesn't work

Comment: You're showing `.nav-menu` by hovering over `#header-nav-menu`, but those are separate elements. So when you hover `#header-nav-menu`, then `.nav-menu` shows. When you move your mouse away from `#header-nav-menu` over to `.nav-menu` you stop hovering `#header-nav-menu`, so `.nav-menu` hides. There are a few ways you could address it. 1) like caramba said, make the trigger to show `.nav-menu` be when you hover `nav` instead. Though that's kind of weird because it will create a big area to hover over that isn't just around the image. 2) minimize the space between `#header-nav-menu` and...

Comment: `.nav-menu` so that when you go from hovering one to another, there is no gap. Then change `#header-nav-menu:hover ~ .nav-menu` to `#header-nav-menu:hover ~ .nav-menu, .nav-menu:hover` so that the menu is open if you hover over the image or the nav menu. But that sucks because then you can't space the image and the nav separately for your UI if you want to. 3) introduce a new element to wrap the image and menu, set that new element to `inline-block` or something so it isn't 100% width, and set the menu to open when you hover that element instead. I updated my answer with #3.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you want to `nav:hover ul { display: block; }` so if your mouse is over the `<nav>` then the menu is visible. Then it's is better possible to click on a menu item.

```css
#header-nav-menu{
 display:hidden;
 width:44px;
 height:31px;
 background:url(https://animalcorner.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/elephant-1-720x422.jpg) no-repeat;
 margin-left:50px;
}
#header-nav-menu a:hover{
 border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;
}

ul.nav-menu{
 list-style-type:none;
 margin-left: 50px;
 font-size:20px;
 font-family: Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight:100;
 color:#373436;
 padding:0;
 margin:0 0 0 0;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.nav-menu li{
 display:inline-block;
 margin-left:50px;
}
ul.nav-menu a:link{
 color:#373436;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.nav-menu a:visited{
 color:#373436;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.nav-menu a:hover{
 color:#2778BA;
}


/* BELOW ADAPTS WITH SMALLER BROWSER WINDOW */
@media (max-width: 960px) {
ul.nav-menu, ul.nav-menu:active{
 display:none;
 z-index:999999999999999999999999999999999999;
 position:absolute;
 border:1px solid #f0f;
 border-radius: 2px 0 2px 2px;
}
#header-nav-menu{
 display:inline-block;
}

/* BELOW NOW WORKING */
nav:hover ul{
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
   <a href="#" id="header-nav-menu"></a>
    <ul class="nav-menu">
    <li><a href="../services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="../about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="../contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    </nav>
```

Comment: thanks! true but won't that apply to all the other <nav> tags?

Comment: Indeed, but you don't have shown any other tags nav tags or sub-menues. What you should do then is nested `<ul><li><ul><li></li></ul></li></ul>` inside your `<nav>` and then when you `:hover` on one `<li>` you make the child `<ul>` to display block

Comment: good idea. Not sure why but I've written this code and it does not work: 'ul.nav-menu li a:hover{display:block;}', or 'ul.nav-menu a:hover{display:block;}' - how can it be written correctly?

Comment: @user3760941 check [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kau5h/) from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23722387/2008111)